# Frisby.JS - unexpected token ( when sending a POST with json

Tags: node.js, json, frisby.js

I'm getting the following error,

```
 Error: Error parsing JSON string: Unexpected token <
    Given: <html>
<body>
<p>
  <b>400.</b> Invalid json request: numOfDays=1&amp;checkInDate=2013-04-10.
Make sure that key names and text values are quoted with "
</p>
</body>
</html>
Stacktrace:
```

using the following code:

var frisby = require('frisby');

```
  frisby.create('Ensure proper values in specified keys')
  .post('http://localhost:9090/bookRoom', {"numOfDays": 1 , "checkInDate":"2013-04-10"})
    .expectJSON({
        "checkInDate": "2013-04-10",
        "checkOutDate": "2013-04-11",
        "totalPrice": 130
    })
.toss()
```

I'm trying to pass this JSON - {"numOfDays": 1 , "checkInDate":"2013-04-10"}

EDIT:

It seems that the JSON being passed is in the following format. How do I  get rid of those backslashes?

```
Handling booking request: "{\"numOfDays\":\"1\",\"checkInDate\":\"2013-04-10\"}"
```

Comment: I've edited to include the full error. Sorry It's my first try testing POST with json

Answer (score 1):

Author of Frisby.js here. Please update to Frisby v0.8.5 - this is due to a change in the "request" module that Frisby depends on and uses.

Comment: I am using v0.8.5 and keep getting the same error when trying to post 
```
    .post(
        'myurl',
        {"userId": + _.uniqueId(), "sessionId": + _.uniqueId(), "productId": + _.uniqueId()},
        {json: true}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same problem but I used different parameters for post. Precisely I added `{json: true}` as 3rd parameter and after a few minutes of struggling I removed it and it worked.

It looks your case might be the other way around. Try to put that 3rd parameter in the `post` method call and hope the best.

Related documentation: [API docs](http://frisbyjs.com/docs/api/)

Comment: The request takes exactly 2 parameters :( I've since decided to use node.js and Mocha and did not struggle with any of that. I'd suggest trying that as it's painless :)

Comment: I meant 3rd parameter to the following line: `.post('http://localhost:9090/bookRoom', {"numOfDays": 1 , "checkInDate":"2013-04-10"})`. But as you switched framework, it's not important anymore. ;)